# How to go through exact points with solve_ivp?

Tags: python, scipy, ode, odeint

I have a system of ODE, and I want to change the value of the variables when the solver reaches an exact point in time. 
What I'm trying to do is similar to this [example in Julia](http://tutorials.juliadiffeq.org/html/models/02-conditional_dosing.html)

What I've tried is to do is using else and if to check if the time t has been reached. However, this doesn't work because the array that contains the time doesn't pass through that exact point.
Also tried to use t_eval without success.

Using the same problem showed in the julia example we have:

```py
from scipy.integrate import  solve_ivp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(t, u):
    if t == 4 and u[0] < 4:
        u[0] += 10
    du = np.empty(1)
    du[0] = -u[0]
    return du

u0=[10.0]
V = 1
t = [0,10]
u0 = [10.0]
sol = solve_ivp(f,t,u0)

plt.plot(sol.t, sol.y[0])
```

Is there a way to replicate the julia callback function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to exactly replicate that code with a callback, it seems simpler to solve the equations in two stages:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import  solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def f(t, u):
    du = -u
    return du


dose = 10.0

u0 = dose
V = 4

t0 = 0
t1 = 4
t2 = 10

t = np.linspace(t0, t1, 100)
sol1 = solve_ivp(f, [t0, t1], [u0], dense_output=True, t_eval=t)

u0 = sol1.y[0, -1]
if u0 / V < 4:
    u0 += dose

t = np.linspace(t1, t2, 150)
sol2 = solve_ivp(f, [t1, t2], [u0], dense_output=True, t_eval=t)

plt.plot(sol1.t, sol1.y[0], 'b')
plt.plot([sol1.t[-1], sol2.t[0]], [sol1.y[0, -1], sol2.y[0, 0]], 'b--')
plt.plot(sol2.t, sol2.y[0], 'b')
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]